# Eliminating "RightOfferApp" malware

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, malware

I caught this insidious malware. It pops ads in searches and in new tabs in Google chrome. I have erased the folders that it created in Program Files (crap like "JustinBieber") but the ads keep popping up. A full scan by Windows's Defender and another by AVG didn't catch this thing. The only reference that I've found to this is recent, and [in German](http://www.gutefrage.net/frage/rightofferapp-deinstallieren#answers).

Tips?

Comment: What anti-malware software have you used?  Have you read the existing question on how to remove malware from your system?

Comment: "A full scan by Windows's Defender and another by AVG didn't catch this thing."

Comment: So you used Windows Defense which only offers the most basic protection, and AVG which isn't designed to find malware, only malicious files categorized as a virus. Use some other programs.

Comment: I had the same problem and i found a extension installed in Chrome called CoupMania. I uninstalled the extension and the pop ads dissapeared :)

Comment: @andandandand Toni is suggesting that you may have a malicious extension installed in your browser, have you checked what extensions are currently installed and uninstalled any you do not remember installing?

Comment: [Remove Pop-up Ads from Internet Explorer, Firefox and Chrome](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-adware-popup-ads/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was assaulted by this virus as well, and the first 8 searches on Google were search engine ads.  Go to settings, extensions, and delete the ones you have no recollection of.  Also, check that none of your other settings were tampered with, and default if necessary.  I did this and the malware disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

You can see my answer here: https://superuser.com/a/902798/143594

In short: remove all unknown extensions and reinstall/update Chrome so that the Chrome executable (chrome.exe) will be 100% clean.